# mongodb filter documents using values from other collection

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, both with ~1 million documents.

I want to mark documents in col1, if they exist in col2:

```
db.col1.find().forEach(function(c1){
    var c2=db.col2.find(a:c1.a);
    if (c2!=null) {
        c1.mark=true;
        db.col1.save(c1);
    }
});
```

It seems that the above script does not run through all the documents, so I get only a few (~50) updated. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's because `save` [is asynchronous](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#save), and as you start to execute the operations too fast, then it starts to behave oddly. I'd try to change the logic to handle the `save` callbacks so you are in control of how many saves are being done at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me a sample?